# QuickSort trouble java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some problems with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10,
if i set 1 instead of 0 - i will have sorted array with unsorted first element, if i set 0 - i have error
 `public void quicksort() {
    // Recursion
    quicksort(0, counter - 1);
}`

Here is all my code

```
public class Main {
private static int comparations = 0;
private static int swaps = 0;
int[] array;
int[] a;
int counter = 0;
int size;

public void qwe() throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); //provide file name from outside
    while(scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        counter++;
        scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
     a = new int[counter];
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        a[i]=scan2.nextInt(); //fill the array with the integers
    }
}



public int partition(int p, int q) {
    int i = p;
    int j = q + 1;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    int pivot = a[p];
    // Divide into two lists
    do {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        do {
            i++;// As we not get we can increase i
        } while (a[i] < pivot);
        // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        do {
            j--;// As we not get we can increase j
        } while (a[j] > pivot);
        // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        if (i < j) {
            swap(i, j);
        }

    } while (i < j);
    // swap the pivot element and j th element
    swap(p, j);

    return j;
}

private void swap(int p, int j) {
    // exchange the elements
    int temp = a[p];
    a[p] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
    swaps++;
}

public void quicksort() {
    // Recursion
    quicksort(0, counter - 1);
}

public void quicksort(int p, int q) {
    int j;
    if (p < q) {
        // Divide into two lists
        j = partition(p, q);
        // Recursion
        quicksort(p, j - 1);
        quicksort(j + 1, q);
    }
    comparations++;

}

public void print() {
    // print the elements of array
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Main q = new Main();
    q.qwe();
    System.out.println("Before Sort <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    q.print();
    q.quicksort();
    System.out.println("After Sort > > > > > > > > > > > >");
    q.print();
    System.out.println("Comparisons: " + comparations);
    System.out.println("Swaps: " + swaps);

}
}
```

Comment: What line of code produces the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the condition in partition method

```
while(a[i] < pivot && i<q)
```

instead of

```
while(a[i] < pivot)
```

because you have to stop searching bigger value than pivot when you reach at the the end

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to avoid `do{...} while` and use `while` instead.

Something like:

```
public int partition(int p, int q) {
    int i = p;
    int j = q + 1;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    int pivot = a[p];
    // Divide into two lists
    while (i < j) {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        while (a[i] < pivot) {
            i++;// As we not get we can increase i
        }
        // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;// As we not get we can increase j
        }
        // If we have found a values in the left list which is larger then
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        if (i < j) {
            swap(i, j);
        }

    }
    // swap the pivot element and j th element
    swap(p, j);

    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `partition` code isn't correct. As swap should be done on basis of value not on index.

```
 if (i < j) {
    swap(i, j);
 }
```

> [Partitioning:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) *reorder the array so that all elements with **values
>   less than the pivot** come before the pivot*, while all elements with
>   **values greater than the pivot** come after it (equal values can go
>   either way). After this partitioning, the pivot is in its final
>   position. This is called the partition operation.

Also, why are you reading same file twice can't you get the number of elements and elements in same loop ?